# AndroidPlot Pie Chart

Tags: android, charts, androidplot

I am using AndroidPlot to implement a pie chart in an application, and I would like to break up the label text onto multiple lines and place it over the middle of the pie chart, similar to the effect shown in the picture below. By default the label is placed above the chart on a single line.

I have looked everywhere online for a way to do this, but I can't find one. Any suggestions as to how it can be done?

[image: Pie Chart Image]